# Angular 4 - configuring systemjs

Tags: angular, plugins, systemjs, ecmascript-5, es6-module-loader

I am using [systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) as a module loader for the first time. I am also trying to use [ng2-drag-drop plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-drag-drop) in my project. After installing it, I have imported the module in the model where I would like to use it, in my case that is the `PostModule`.

```
import { Ng2DragDropModule } from 'ng2-drag-drop';

@NgModule({
  imports: [PostRoutingModule, SharedModule, Ng2DragDropModule],
  declarations: [PostComponent],
  exports: [PostComponent],
  providers: [PostService]
})
export class PostModule { }
```

And as it says in the docs, I have changed the `systemjs` config file:

```
declare var System: SystemJSLoader.System;

System.config(JSON.parse('<%= SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV %>'));
System.config({
    map: {
        'ng2-drag-drop': 'node_modules/ng2-drag-drop'
    },
    packages: {
        'ng2-drag-drop':  { main: 'index.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    }
});
```

But, I get an error:

> GET
>   http://localhost:5555/node_modules/node_modules/ng2-drag-drop/index.js
>   404 (Not Found) (anonymous)
>   (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
>   http://localhost:5555/node_modules/node_modules/ng2-drag-drop/index.js

Comment: I also think that if you added a slash before `node_modules` here `'ng2-drag-drop': '/node_modules/ng2-drag-drop'` it should work as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can configure it:

```
System.config({
    paths: {
        'npm:': '/node_modules/'
    },

    map: {
        'ng2-drag-drop': 'npm:ng2-drag-drop'
    },

    packages: {
        'ng2-drag-drop': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }

    }
```